vs code shortcut to open mdn reference from hover
It would be great to be able to have a keyboard shortcut that will click this MDN reference link when I have the hover appear. I often trigger the hover with the keyboard, but I can't open the link without using the mouse. Does anyone have an idea how I could do so?
css hover with mdn reference link
Looked for shortcut binding but couldn't find one
